# Click the menuitem js

Tags: javascript

```
    < div class = "chatMessagesMenu goog-menu"
role = "menu"
aria - haspopup = "true"
tabindex = "0"
style = "user-select: none; left: 366px; top: 539px;" > < div class = "goog-menuitem delete"
role = "menuitem"
id = ":1k"
style = "user-select: none;" > < div class = "goog-menuitem-content"
style = "user-select: none;" > Seçileni sil < /div></div > < div class = "goog-menuitem ban"
role = "menuitem"
id = ":1l"
style = "user-select: none;" > < div class = "goog-menuitem-content"
style = "user-select: none;" > Yasaklama kaydetti < /div></div > < div class = "goog-menuitem kick"
role = "menuitem"
id = ":1m"
style = "user-select: none;" > < div class = "goog-menuitem-content"
style = "user-select: none;" > Başlamayı kaydetti < /div></div > < div class = "goog-menuitem cancel"
role = "menuitem"
id = ":1n"
style = "user-select: none;" > < div class = "goog-menuitem-content"
style = "user-select: none;" > İptal < /div></div > < /div>
```

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ze3.png)

I have this code and this menu. I want to click first menu item of this menu. I wrote this code to the console.

```
 $('.chatMessagesMenu.goog-menu').firstElementChild.getElementsByClassName('goog-menuitem-content')[0]
```

But it doesn't click. It says "undefined". How can I click? please help.

Comment: Why all those nasty spaces in HTML? Why `aria - haspopup` with spaces? Please stop programming in "Notepad". There are better IDEs out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to happen when a user clicks a certain element, you need to add an 'event listener' to that element. Using JQuery it looks something like this:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function(e) {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
  // more code here to do whatever
});
```

Where `"#target"` is whatever element you want to click on.

Good luck! and maybe try to format your code a little so it's easier to look at.